# How to connect mongoDB Compass to a mongoDB instance that runs on Google Cloud VM Instance?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-compass

This should be much easier than it is..
I installed a MongoDB instance on a GCP VM Instance, opened the needed ports, verified the app is running locally but for some reason I can't make it work from my local machine's Compass.
My authentication method with the GCP VM instance is with the ssh key file.
I am not sure if such parameter exists in the Compass or how can I set it up in order to being able to connect..
Can't really find anything sufficient here as well..
Thanks!

Some more context as it seems I still cannot gain an access..
This is the setting I have in the conf file:

```
    # network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

I checked in the GCP firewall rules and I have this port wide open. I tried disabling the firewall as well just to see if something goes through but still nothing.

What is interesting though is I have some chatter in the mongo logs that imply that I do receive requests through the firewall:

```
2020-04-15T10:30:19.728+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.x.x.x:63003 #11 (11 connections now open)
2020-04-15T10:30:19.731+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn11] received client metadata from 10.x.x.x:63003 conn11: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "19.4.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.2.0, LE (unified)", application: { name: "MongoDB Compass" } }
```

I have a code that attempts to access MongoDB with the Python driver and I get the same chatter but no connection ultimately..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problems stem from my company's Firewall that probably drop the incoming requests :/ 
The firewall is Palo Alto's Global Protect